# p64() from pwntools not working correctly

Tags: c, python-2.7, format-string, pwntools

I want to send input to a process which includes unprintable characters like "\x90". I when I try to send it like this: `p.sendline(p64(0x414190))`, my programm which prints it back, returns `AA\x90`. It took the "\x90" as a string, not as a byte. Can someone help me how to send raw bytes?

My program (vulnerable to format string, I dont need to be told):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char name[512];
  char passwd[512];

  printf("Enter your name: ");
  fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
  printf(name);

  printf("Enter your password: ");
  fgets(passwd, sizeof(passwd), stdin);
  printf(passwd);

  exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `p64()` does send the input as raw bytes. You can check it by adding pwntools' `DEBUG` flag while running your script. The debug output then prints everything that is sent and received. E.g.:

```
python2 solve.py DEBUG
[+] Starting local process './script': pid 23732
[DEBUG] Received 0x11 bytes:
    'Enter your name: '
[DEBUG] Sent 0x9 bytes:
    00000000  90 41 41 00  00 00 00 00  0a                        │·AA·│····│·│
    00000009
[*] Switching to interactive mode
[DEBUG] Received 0x18 bytes:
    00000000  90 41 41 45  6e 74 65 72  20 79 6f 75  72 20 70 61  │·AAE│nter│ you│r pa│
    00000010  73 73 77 6f  72 64 3a 20                            │sswo│rd: │
    00000018
\x90AAEnter your password: $
```

In the example above, you see that the bytes `90 41 41 00  00 00 00 00  0a` are sent to the program, and not the string `\x90`.

Comment: And btw, I left out explaining why it is printed as the string `\x90` because I have no idea. I guess it is because 0x90 is a non-printable character. I cannot find it in the ASCII table, so maybe the hex value is printed to look good or something.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the pwntools is exactly working as normal, the true problem is produced by python's grammar.
If you only use print() to print the feedback, python will consider it as a 'string' but not 'byte'.